# Changing shown URL after GET Request

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc

Currently I have 2 pages based on the following URL `MyNewApp/purchase` and `MyNewApp/confirm`. On the 2nd page that is /confirm I added a back button with the following

**HTML**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn" id="back">
Go Back
</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('button[id="back"]').click(function() {
    this.form.action="backToPurchase";
    this.form.method="GET";
});
```

After pressing the back button everything works fine except the URL changed to `/MyNewApp/backToPurchase?_method=`. How can I set the URL to `/MyNewApp/purchase` after pressing the back button ?

Comment: Did you try changing `this.form.action` to be just `"purchase"`?

Comment: I have a controller that handles /purchase which will initialize the whole form. What I want just to get back to the previous form with the entered information.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to emulate the browser's back button. Have you considered using `window.history.back()` to return to the previous page?

Comment: that JS function will trigger the initialization of the form. I guess I'll have to follow what's been suggested by @Guy to change my request to `POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can't just change the URL as you wish.
Think about it, if you could change the URL like that it would be a big security problem.

BUT try to use POST instead, or just send the user to a new page so the URL will change, You have lots of options to solve it, just think.

Answer (score 1):

This is technically the answer to your question, though you might want to think about a better way to do what you want.

window.history.pushState(null, null, “/new-url”);

Comment: May I know what is the better way ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a better option, instead of submitting a form just for redirection, use the following:

```
$('#back').click(function() {// <-- selecting by id is much faster than selecting by attribute "id"
    location.href = '/backToPurchase'; // or '/purchase';
    // OR you can do the following :
    history.back(); //this will performs as you clicked the back btn from the browser
});
```